# How to create an output (csv file) for each text file with the same name in a directory?

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am trying to find word frequency for each text file and save the output word frequency of each text file into a csv file with same name.

```
Ahja_Shaank_OP.txt to Ahja_Shaank_OP.csv
Bhjg_Dhaenk_OP.txt to Bhjg_Dhaenk_OP.csv
.
.
500 files
```

.

```
pacman::p_load(pacman, tm, SnowballC, dplyr)

infiles <- dir(pattern='\\.txt$')

#docs <- Corpus(DirSource("D:\\PavanSOP\\txt"))

change.files <- function(file){

  bookJE <- readLines(file)

  # Preliminary corpus
  corpusJE <- Corpus(VectorSource(bookJE)) %>%
    tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
    #tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
    tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")) %>%
    tm_map(stripWhitespace) 
  #tm_map(stemDocument)

  # Create term-document matrices & remove sparse terms
  tdmJE <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpusJE) %>%
    removeSparseTerms(1 - (1/length(corpusJE)))

  # Calculate and sort by word frequencies
  word.freqJE <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(tdmJE)), 
                      decreasing = T)

  # Create frequency table
  tableJE <- data.frame(word = names(word.freqJE), 
                        absolute.frequency = word.freqJE, 
                        relative.frequency = 
                          word.freqJE/length(word.freqJE))

  # Remove the words from the row names
  rownames(tableJE) <- NULL

  # Show the 10 most common words
  head(tableJE, 10)

  #write.csv(file)
  #write.table(x, file = $file.csv, sep = ",", col.names = NA,
              qmethod = "double")
  write.table(data, quote=FALSE, sep=", ", sub("\\.txt$",".csv", file))

}

lapply(infiles , change.files)
```

And how do I extract the filename and save it as csv?
Any idea why this is not working?

```
  write.table(data, quote=FALSE, sep=", ", sub("\\.txt$",".csv", file))
```

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: `?list.files` ; `?purrr::map` OR `?lapply` (you could use `for` in this case though); you may also need to `?sprintf` or `?paste`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you. I used the lapply help. I have updated the code. Could you please help in why the csv files are not getting created?